# pandas: filter intraday df by non-consecutive list of dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframes of 1 minute bars going back years (the datetime is the index). I need to get a set of bars covering an irregular (non-consecutive) long list of dates.

For daily bars, I could do something like this:

```
datelist = ['20140101','20140205']
dfFiltered = df[df.index.isin(datelist)]
```

However if I try that on 1 minute bar data, it only gives me the bars with time 00:00:00, e.g. in this case it gives me two bars for 20140101 00:00:00 and 20140205 00:00:00.

My actual source df will look something like:

```
df1m = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('20100101', '20140730', freq='1min'),
                    data={'open':3, 'high':4, 'low':1, 'close':2}
                   ).between_time('00:00:00', '07:00:00')
```

Is there any better way to get all the bars for each day in the list than looping over the list? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a date column based on the index

```
df1m['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1m.index.date)
```

Then use that column when filtering

```
datelist = ['20140101','20140205']
df1m[df1m['date'].isin(datelist)]
```

Comment: Thank you - simple and effective. I was actually able to do without the extra column by just directly doing: `df1m[pd.to_datetime(df1m.index.date).isin(datelist)]`